# Geofencing works only for recently added one

Tags: android, android-geofence

I am registering Geofences like this:

```
public void addGeofencing(final MyObject myObject){

            Geofence geofence = (new Geofence.Builder()
                    .setRequestId(myObject.getId())

                    .setCircularRegion(
                            myObject.getLat(),
                            myObject.getLon(),
                            RADIUS_IN_METERS
                    )
                    .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
                            Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                    .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                    .build());

            client.addGeofences(getGeofencingRequest(geofence),getGeofencePendingIntent(myObject.getExtraString))
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            System.out.println("GEOFENCE WORKED");
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("GEOFENCE FAILED");
                }
            });


    }


    private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest(Geofence geofence) {
        GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
        builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
        builder.addGeofence(geofence);
        return builder.build();
    }
    private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent(String extraString) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
        intent.putExtra("extra",extraString);
        return PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }
```

But while doing so I noticed that enter and exit events are being triggered only for the most recent geofence that I add. Why is that and how can I fix that? I am setting unique request id for each geofence so that should prevent that problem?